# How to create Embedded Media Field: Video with custom resolution per Views field

Tags: views, files

Is there a way to apply a custom resolution to an Embedded Media Field: Video at the time of building a View? Alternatively, a way to define more than the just the Full / Preview presets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it in the `template_preprocess_node()`

depending on your view mode you can set the first element :

```
if ($vars['view_mode'] == "full") {

   $node->video_field_name[0]['#settings']['width'] = '300';
   $node->video_field_name[0]['#settings']['height'] = '150';

}
```

dont forget to set all elements, not just the first one

other settings you can set:

```
#settings
  controls (Boolean) TRUE
  width (String) 300
  height (String) 150
  download_link (Boolean) FALSE
  download_text (String) Download
```

**Edit**:

[`template_preprocess_views_view_field`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--views--theme--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_field/7) is what you need for views probably. there you can access to the $vars['row'] with all data you need. maybe you will need to rerender the field.

If this does not work there is a workaround:
the embedded-media-field sets its settings in the drupal js-settings.
get the js settings with `drupal_add_js()`, find the element `mediaelement` and set the settings manually.

Comment: I'm outputting it from a View with Fields display, not a Node display, so if there's a preprocess function to handle this I'm not aware of it.

Comment: template_preprocess_views_view_field, see edit...

Comment: Well unfortunately I was unable to find the field object from within the variables provided to `template_preprocess_views_view_field`, no how to invoke a rerendering of the field. In the end I went real dirty and use preg_replace to alter the width/height.